# Array processing and Table handling with packed decimal in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I was practicing array processing and table handling and there's this output of my program that I don't understand.

```
01  TABLE-VALUES.                      
    05 TABLE-ELEMENTS OCCURS 2 TIMES. 
       10 A-A PIC X(5).                
       10 A-B PIC S9(5)V99 COMP-3.     
01  WS-STRING PIC X(10).               
01  S PIC 99.                          
01  WS-COUNT PIC 99.                   
...
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                       
0000-MAIN.                                                
    DISPLAY 'HELLO WORLD'                                 
    MOVE '1234567890ABCDEFGHI' TO TABLE-VALUES            
    DISPLAY 'TABLE VALUES ' TABLE-VALUES                  
    MOVE 0 TO WS-COUNT                                    
    INSPECT TABLE-VALUES TALLYING WS-COUNT FOR CHARACTERS 
    DISPLAY WS-COUNT                                      
    PERFORM 1000-PARA VARYING S FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL S > 2  
    STOP RUN.                                             
1000-PARA.                                                
    MOVE 'A-A(&&) = ' TO WS-STRING                        
    INSPECT WS-STRING REPLACING FIRST '&&' BY S           
    DISPLAY WS-STRING A-A(S)  
    MOVE 'A-B(&&) = ' TO WS-STRING              
    INSPECT WS-STRING REPLACING FIRST '&&' BY S 
    DISPLAY WS-STRING A-B(S).
```

The output turned out to be:

```
HELLO WORLD                                                                     
TABLE VALUES 1234567890ABCDEFGHI                                                
18                                                                              
A-A(01) = 12345                                                                 
A-B(01) =  6 7 8                                                                
A-A(02) = 0ABCD                                                                 
A-B(02) =  5 6 7
```

I don't understand how A-B(1) and A-B(2) turned out like that. Why are there spaces in between? Where did digit 9 go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `COMP-3` from the `A-B` definition, it should work better.

#### Cobol comp-3

**Comp-3** is cobol's binary coded decimal format. Each 4 bytes (1/2 byte or nyble) represents a decimal digit with the sign held in the last digit. Moving a character string to a comp-3 value (like you do) will result in a invalid comp-3 value.

Normally the value 1234 would be stored as

```
`01234C`x
```

In your case (if using an EBCDIC machine) you are moving `6789` hex string 'f6f7f8f9'x
to the variable `A-B(01)`. The F's are not valid decimal digits and 9 is not a valid comp-3 sign.

#### Move to Table Explanation

Explanation of

```
MOVE '1234567890ABCDEFGHI' TO TABLE-VALUES
```

in the above `TABLE-VALUES` is treated as a `pic x(18)`. The move completely ignores the definitions of **A-A** and **A-B**.

Assuming a definition of

```
01  TABLE-VALUES.                      
    05 TABLE-ELEMENTS OCCURS 2 TIMES. 
       10 A-A PIC X(5).                
       10 A-B PIC S9(5)V99.
```

The following would make more sense

```
MOVE 'A-A 100234567A-A 200234567' TO TABLE-VALUES
```

When doing a move to a *group level*, The string has to exactly match the
map of the **fields** in the Group.

For the above Cobol Layout, the fields are aligned like

```
   Field    Position  Length
   A-A(1)      1        5
   A-B(1)      6        7
   A-A(2)      13       5
   A-B(2)      18       7
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now very well!

Comment: A-B(1) = 67890AB, A-B(2) = HI. This is the result after removing comp-3. Why were the letters moved? I thought a picture of 9 only accepts numerical data?

Comment: @rogerStrycova
 I have updated the answer with an explanation of group level moves

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know which compiler and directives you are using, but I would have expected the original DISPLAY of the comp-3 usage to ABEND with a numeric exception.

As for the follow up question about the letters in the numeric field, you valued the field by moving a literal to a group item, TABLE-VALUES. Group items always are USAGE ALPHANUMERIC.

Comment: You wrote: *Group items always are USAGE ALPHANUMERIC.* That is not correct. Group items are `USAGE DISPLAY` with class and category alphanumeric.